# SQL EXCLUDE records with timestamps defined in the separate table

Tags: sql

I need to write SQL that EXCLUDES records with date in a certain date range. The range is defined by another table.

First TABLE1 looks like this:

DATE        VALUE

```
'1-jan-15 00:00'., 123
'1-jan-15 00:01'., 999
................., ...
'15-jan-15 16:42', ...
```

Second TABLE2 looks like this:

```
START_DATE        END_DATE
'4-jan-15 12:05', '4-jan-15 12:17' 
'7-jan-15 12:15', '4-jan-15 14:10' 
etc
```

I need all the values from TABLE1 except the ones with the timestamp between TABLE2.START_DATE and TABLE2.END_DATE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Inner Join` the two tables using `Not Between` Operator

```
SELECT datavalue
FROM   table1 a
       INNER JOIN table2 b
               ON a.datavalue NOT BETWEEN b.start_date AND b.endate
```

Comment: @Tigger, if it worked, accept the answer to close out the question